# How to check in Cypress that we redirected to the same page?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I'm using Vue and Cypress. I have a page with logo that redirects to the home page.
Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="text-center" id="app-header">
      <a href=".">
        <img src="../assets/logo.png" style="width: 128px; height: 128px;"/> 
      </a>
      <h1 class="mb-3" style="font-weight: bold;">TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <view id="app-body"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now I want to check if clicking the image, actually redirects to the home page (my app consists of only one main page). I could check if the url is the url of the home page but since you are already inside the home page, I don't feel like it's a good test. How can I test that the url has been redirected to the home page, instead of just check if I'm currently looking at the home page?

Comment: click on href then check for the path and it should be equal to '/'.
pls refer - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#No-Args

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to spy on the request made to the homepage URL and make sure it was successful. I just checked this and it works for me. You may need slight modifications like changing the logo's `id` and the path of the `cy.intercept` to match your app. Here are the steps:

1. `cy.intercept` requests going to the homepage URL and give them an alias.
2. Click the logo.
3. Use the alias to check that the request to the homepage URL was successful.
4. Any other checks you might want to do, like `cy.location` or checking for various homepage elements to make sure that the redirect really loaded your homepage successfully.

```js
it("clicking logo reloads/redirects to homepage", () => {
  cy.intercept("/app/home").as("homepage");

  cy.get("#logoThatRedirectsToHomepage").click();
  cy.wait("@homepage").its("response.statusCode").should("eq", 200);
});
```